# Angularjs : format number according to locale

Tags: angularjs

I need to display this number 2387,15
I am doing this with angularjs :

```
{{myNumber|number:2}}
```

I am getting 2,387.15
I dont want a coma betwen 2 and 3 (I am french).

Is there a way to set the locale with angularjs?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Approach #1**. If you want french locale then you can simply include corresponding localization file. For example:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.4.5/angular-locale_fr-fr.js"></script>
```

Then Angular will pick it up and use for all localization.

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-i18n/1.4.5/angular-locale_fr-fr.js"></script>
<script>
  angular.module('demo', []).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myNumber = 2387,15;
  });
</script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  {{myNumber|number:2}}
</div>
```

**Approach #2**. Another simple thing you can do is to customize `NUMBER_FORMATS.GROUP_SEP` constant:

```js
angular.module('demo', []).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $locale) {
    $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.GROUP_SEP = ' ';
    $scope.myNumber = 2387,15;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    {{myNumber|number:2}}    
</div>
```

Comment: hi I tried 2nd approach but it still shows 2 387,00